# R library path is not recognised when invoked in php code

Tags: php, r, apache, package

I would like to know why my data table generated using following code (mytable.R) is not able to save the html file using *saveWidget* argument when used inside php code.

```
library(DT)
load.this <- "DT"
data <- as.matrix(read.table("/path/to/file.txt", header = TRUE, fill = TRUE))

table <- datatable(data, filter = 'top', options = list(columnDefs = list(list(targets = c(1, 3), searchable = FALSE)),pageLength = 10))     

saveWidget(table, "test.html", selfcontained = TRUE, libdir = NULL,
       background = "white", knitrOptions = list())
```

PHP code that calls the mytable.R is,

```
echo exec("Rscript /var/www/html/fam/R/mytable.R $size");
```

However, issuing the following command from terminal generated and saved file in the directory.

```
Rscript mytable.R
```

Alternatively, 1)  I tried **htmlwidgets** instead of **DT**

```
          2)  saveWidget(table, file="test.html")
```

In both case, the problem persisted. Can anyone please suggest me why the file is not saved?

Edit:

I installed the DT package in the server using following command,

```
sudo R
install.packages("DT", lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/")
```

Answer (score 2):

It was an issue with DT package dependencies.

```
install.packages("DT", lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/", dependencies = TRUE)
```

couldn't recognize the package. However, when I manually load each package from the list [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/), it was successful.